# Not randomising file names because of a problem

Tags: python, shutil

I'm beginning to learn python and I thought I should try to make a program.
So I tried to make minecraft texture randomizer. I think my code makes sense but there is a huge problem I did not think through. When I rename the files in a random order. It cant rename for example. "Obsidian.png" -> "Endstone.png" as obsidian so I tried using `os.mkdir()` and copy the file and paste it into that folder, then it would rename that file, however there is still a message. And just to clarify I will make it so it will delete the old folder and rename the new folder to the same name.

My code:

```
import random
import shutil

def my_shuffle(arr):
    random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

os.chdir('C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item')
oldTextures = os.listdir()
newRandomizedTextures = my_shuffle(os.listdir())

print(newRandomizedTextures)
i = 0

os.mkdir("C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item1")

for x in newRandomizedTextures:
    shutil.copy('C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item/' + oldTextures[i], 'C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item1')
    os.rename('C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item1/' + oldTextures[i], 'C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets/minecraft/textures/item1/' + newRandomizedTextures[i])
    i = i + 1
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC Specialist\Documents\Python\pythonProject\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item1")
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\\minecraft/textures/item1'
```

Comment: `shutil.move` doesn't work for you? https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC Specialist\Documents\Python\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    shutil.move('C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item/' + oldTextures[i], 'C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item1')
  File "D:\stuff\lib\shutil.py", line 804, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:/Users/PC Specialist/Documents/Python Scripts/r/assets\minecraft/textures/item1\bone_meal.png' already exists

Answer (score 0):

Your original error is because of the mkdir line. The second time you run the script it will try to make that same dir again. You could just manually create the dir and remove that line or put a try/except around it and ignore the error:

```
try:
    os.mkdir("/blah")
except FileExistsError:
    # ignore
    pass
```

I think it's a similar problem when you're testing your shutil.move. You should clean the directory between runs.

One neat trick you can use:

```
for i, newTexture in enumerate(newRandomizedTextures):
    print(i)
    print(newTexture)
```

enumerate will give you the index.

Comment: [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) lets you robustly create a directory which doesn't exist, but do nothing if it does, without `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 0):

For each set of files which will replace each other, you will need to rename at least one of the files to a temporary name. But the simple brute-force solution is to rename all your files twice: First, to a temporary name, then to the final names, now that none of them will be taken.

Here is a quick and dirty sketch:

```py
import shutil
import os
import random

originals = os.scandir('.')
for idx, file in enumerate(originals):
    shutil.move(file, 'temp%08i.png' % idx)

random.shuffle(originals)
for idx, file in enumerate(originals):
    shutil.move('temp%08i.png' % idx, file)
```

This will leave some temporary files behind if you interrupt it midway through; probably keep a list of the original file names handy somewhere, in case that happens (probably with checksums so you can discover which contents go with which original file name).

Notice also that this will rename files in the current directory; don't run it somewhere important!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but as i said i am a beginner. What does this code do exactly and do i just paste that code and delete my code?

Comment: You probably want to keep the `os.chdir` after the `import` statements, but other than that, yeah. I can't help but think that this should be obvious, and quite similar to your original code, only simpler. The preference for `scandir` over `listdir` is a minor optimization.